# Acceptable Data Types for KNeighborsClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, knn

I was expecting the below code to only accept
data type `category` for `y`, since by definition a classifier predicts a value for categorical variables. But after testing I saw that this classifier accepts `y` values that are `integer`, `object` etc. Is it converting the `y` to `category` behind the scenes, or what's happening here?

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier  
classifier = KNeighborsClassifier() 
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train) 
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Please use some dummy data to post a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is actually not happening anything in that regard. I don't know where you got this from that the target `y` could only be of type `category` (which is by the way not a [numpy dtype](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html#numpy-dtype) but a thing of pandas). But there is no need for such a restriction.

`scikit-learn` internally uses a function called [`type_of_target`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/2beed55847ee70d363bdbfe14ee4401438fba057/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py#L186) to check that the target `y` is in accordance with the API specifications and determine a `target_type`, i.e. what kind of classification task it is. Here is an excerpt of its docstring:

```py
Examples
    --------
    >>> import numpy as np
    >>> type_of_target([0.1, 0.6])
    'continuous'
    >>> type_of_target([1, -1, -1, 1])
    'binary'
    >>> type_of_target(['a', 'b', 'a'])
    'binary'
    >>> type_of_target([1.0, 2.0])
    'binary'
    >>> type_of_target([1, 0, 2])
    'multiclass'
    >>> type_of_target([1.0, 0.0, 3.0])
    'multiclass'
    >>> type_of_target(['a', 'b', 'c'])
    'multiclass'
    >>> type_of_target(np.array([[1, 2], [3, 1]]))
    'multiclass-multioutput'
    >>> type_of_target([[1, 2]])
    'multilabel-indicator'
    >>> type_of_target(np.array([[1.5, 2.0], [3.0, 1.6]]))
    'continuous-multioutput'
    >>> type_of_target(np.array([[0, 1], [1, 1]]))
    'multilabel-indicator'
```

A classification task is any of the follwoing:

```py
['binary', 'multiclass', 'multiclass-multioutput', 
'multilabel-indicator', 'multilabel-sequences']
```

So the types of the elements can be `int`, `str` or `object`, but not `float`.